custom classifier/splitter dataset test limit
I am currently working on a project that utilizes the docai custom classifier. I have a question regarding the test dataset size limitations.
As I understand, the current limit for the test dataset size is 2,000 documents. However, for my project, I would like to increase the number of test samples beyond this limit, I have a total of 20k+ documents which is within the training dataset limits. Could you please advise on the best way to achieve this?
Is there a way to bypass or increase the 2,000 document limit for the test dataset? If so, what are the steps I need to follow to do so? Additionally, are there any considerations or potential implications I should be aware of when working with a larger test dataset?
I would greatly appreciate your guidance on this matter. Your expertise in the GCP Document AI service would be invaluable in helping me address this requirement for my project.
Training a datasets beyond 2k limit with result an error that the test dataset is beyond the maximum.
